# PHP Infinite loop when user not logged in

Tags: php, session, loops, header, infinite

I am having an infinite loop issue with this code. It's checking to see if there is a session variable, if there isn't, I want them to be redirected to the index page.

```
session_start();
   if (! isset($_SESSION['foo'])) {
     header('Location: /index.php');
   }
exit;
```

I've tried putting the exit; and exit(); and endif; outside the if loop and inside, all are still giving me the issue of infinite loops. This code is located in the header page, which is then called on every page, so you can only access the index page if you are not logged in. That's the gist of why I want this code to exist in the first place.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You mentioned that this code is located on the header page, which is located on EVERY page. 

If this code is also located on your index page, then the index page would be checking for the session variable too, leading to hte infinite loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add something to your if statement that would exclude the index.php page. Something like

```
if(! isset($_SESSION['foo']) && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'index.php') === false) {
    header('Location: /index.php');
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't test request_uri like that... easy enough to gain access to unauthorized pages by simply doing something like `http://example.com/realpage.php?haha_Im_in_ur_sitez=index.php`

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand what you are trying to say here. I will go with your answer and change my code accordingly. Although Marc said not to use request_uri like this, I will see if this works.

Answer (score 0):

If you make that check on the index page, it will redirect loop whenever a session is not set. You need to make sure this check is not made on index.php

Comment: That's basically what the answer above yours is saying. So if you come from index, you shouldn't do the redirect. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing session_start();

page.php :

```
<?php
session_start(); // this is important
if (! isset($_SESSION['foo'])) {
    header('Location: /index.php');
    exit;
}
?>
```

index.php :

```
<?php
session_start(); // this is important

//stuff

$_SESSION['foo'] = 'stuff';

//other stuff
?>
```

Comment: I just forgot to include it in my code. I'm very sorry. I have it there before the if statement just like you have. Thank you so much though! You are awesome :D